# Stumped by electrical issue, exterior light wiring tripping breaker

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker

Out of the blue, had a breaker trip and when I went to reset it, it kept tripping over and over.  Mistakenly I replaced the breaker before anything else only to find out that wasn't the issue.

After more troubleshooting I narrowed it down to the wiring on one outdoor light.  When I remove the light and just leave the wiring completely undone, the breaker will not trip.

Does not trip when light is off and wiring is like this, notice two black wires apart: https://i.ibb.co/FwGRHpB/PXL-20231217-181816654.jpg

When I hook the light up, as it was, the breaker trips.  The tricky part that makes me think it's not the actually the light, is that when the light is completely removed and I connect the two black wires, the breaker trips.  So something about these two wires connecting it causing the issue.  Photo, the breaker trips once those two black wires are connected, theyre connected under the orange cap: https://i.ibb.co/SdfbxvV/PXL-20231217-181715739.jpg

The interesting part is the light is hooked up in a 3 way connection with the black wires.  Those two black wires which originate from different locations within the box (wall) connect together with a third black wire that goes to the light. The white ones are also connected similarly but do not trip the breaker. Light with hook ups:  https://i.ibb.co/JrTNvrX/PXL-20231217-181428311.jpg

Hopefully the pictures help explain since I'm likely not doing a good job in writing.

This is how the light has been hooked up for a couple years now and has been working fine up until now.

If this enters into call an electrician territory, can I just cap the wires and put some sort of cover on the box and forego even having a light hooked up?

Photo of inside box, you can see the black wires originate from two different locations withing the box:  https://i.ibb.co/Jz3tYPD/PXL-20231217-175520438.jpg

How they were hooked up when I originally pulled the light off:  https://i.ibb.co/k1G0hDr/PXL-20231217-175407225.jpg

Comment: One of the black wires has a short in it somewhere.  I imagine the second black wire goes to another light?  Turn off the breaker and make sure there is no power at those wires(turning off the wrong breaker is common), remove the metal ring thing and check the wire insulation carefully.  Repeat at the other light and switch.  Mice damaged wires is also a possibility.

Comment: "light is hooked up in a 3 way connection" does this mean that there are two switches that control this light or simply that there were 3 wires per wire nut? Also, please remove the silver mounting bracket so we can see how the wires pair up into cables as they leave this box.

Comment: @FreeMan Thanks, there is only one switch that control this light.  The switch also controls another outdoor light that is working normally.  Here is behind the bracket that shows how the two black wires originate from different locations:  https://i.ibb.co/Jz3tYPD/PXL-20231217-175520438.jpg

Comment: @crip659 Added two photos of what it looks like behind the bracket: 1.  https://i.ibb.co/Jz3tYPD/PXL-20231217-175520438.jpg


2. https://i.ibb.co/k1G0hDr/PXL-20231217-175407225.jpg

There is another light on this line that is working normally.  Thanks

Comment: The way this is wired has nothing to do with the 3-way feeding it. The switch-leg (hot or black) is connected to one side. The neutral is connected to the other. The second wire must go to another fixture and the short is somewhere in that line. Using the breaker as a testing device is NOT the best way to test this. With the breaker OFF, and the black wires disconnected in the fixture, and no bulb in the other fixture, check for continuity between black of suspect wire and the bare wire. There should be no continuity or the problem is in the wire or the second fixture.

Comment: @RGHughes I think I'm tracking.  If theres continuity in the wire, it could be anywhere along the line from the first light to the second light?  Thanks

Comment: No need to edit the answer into the question. Clicking the check mark (as you've already done) is all that's needed to let others know what the answer is. Also, no need to tag something as `edit` or `update`. Simply click the `edited <x time> ago` link to see the edit history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your explanation and the look of the ground wire in the box, I would think that you have another box for another light somewhere that most likely was burried in stucco during construction (or altered in remodel).  Unless there is another outdoor light which does not work? The corrosion and discoloring of the ground wires indicate they have been carrying a current for some time.  There has been an "almost" short in the wire going to next light, which finally graduated to a real short. The 2 black wires in box: 1 comes from the switch (after passing thru the light that still works) and the other would continue on to a third light somewhere.  It is in that wire that your problem exists. Try connecting the light to just one black wire. When you turn ît on, if nothing happens then connect to other black wire. Install wire nut (the orange cap) on the unused wire.

Comment: Thank you.  I am not aware of a third light on this chain, but who knows, old house full of surprises.  It seems odd that it would have been working all this time and then stopped.  I'll give it a go connecting to just one wire at a time, that would be a nice solution to all this.  Will update

Comment: Awesome, that worked.  Thanks again, simple fix.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I would check the second fixture before worrying about the wire. High odds it's the fixture. Note. Don't disconnect the white wire. (the bare and white are connected at the main panel so testing one gets both)